# Enigmail Public Key Reference

Tags: thunderbird, public-key, enigmail

I seem to remember in earlier versions of EnigMail, the Thunderbird add-on that it was possible to have it display the location of your public key (name & server). This doesn't seem to be the case any more. This was a useful; feature for me as I tend to use a single public key for several accounts, but would like to indicate the key being used to sign the message. It seems to me that it would be a good practice to advertise where your public key is available as there are many key servers.

- Does anyone know how to activate this functionality again (other than a sig) ?
- Is it a bad security practice to advertise where your key is?

(My current versions are Thunderbird 3.1.6 and EnigMail 1.1.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: If you look at the individual settings for each account, under "OpenPGP Security", if you select the "Use PGP/MIME by default" option, in the advanced settings you can specify that you want to send your keyID, and also which server to look for it on.